# Unity - Detection between two different types of colliders is not working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have two different type colliders in a `gameobject`: a sphere collider for a trigger and a capsule collider for a hit raycast. I have this code for the `OnTriggerEnter` but nothing happens when the player enters in the sphere trigger. What am I doing wrong?

```
public GameObject canvasTesoroFoto;
public GameObject canvasTesoroDatos;

private GameObject Player;
public SphereCollider sCollider;
public CapsuleCollider cCollider;

void Start()
{
    Player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player");
    sCollider = GetComponent<SphereCollider> ();
    cCollider = GetComponent<CapsuleCollider> ();

}

void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other == sCollider) {
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "Player") {
            canvasTesoroFoto.SetActive (true);
            canvasTesoroDatos.SetActive (true);
        }
    } 
    if (other == cCollider) {
        Debug.Log ("HitCollider");
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: This code in what game object is attached? in the player or in the obstacle?

Comment: @IgnacioAlorre In the obstacle.

Comment: Ok, I edtied the answer. So just the sphere has the trigger or also the capsule?

Comment: The sphere has the trigger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it work you will need:

- In the obstacle: The Sphere collider with the is trigger checked

In the player:

- A collider
- A rigidbody

Besides, if the scrip is in the obstacle, the collider `other` will refer to the player NOT to the OBSTACLE. So you should do directly like this:

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "Player") {
            canvasTesoroFoto.SetActive (true);
            canvasTesoroDatos.SetActive (true);
        }
}
```

Based on your comment. In that case you should consider add the trigger in the collider of the player, to detect the sphere of the obstacle, and leave the trigger for the capsule.

And in case you need that both colliders in the obstacle are triggered, what you can do is to create a sphere gameobject as child of the obstacle, make it transparent and add there the script and sphere collider. Then keep the collider in the obstacle itself. Then you can exchange information between script in the sphere and the obstacle if necessary.

But as far as I know, there is not way to distinguish which of the colliders in the gameobject triggered `OnTriggerEnter()` if both has got checked "is trigger"

**Edit:** based on your comments, I imagine a situation where the GameObejct of the colliders is some kind of enemy which may be hit by raycast and at the same time can crash with the Player (for example to take life from him).

The best approach is to make is trigger the collider of the Player, to detect the sphere collider of the enemy in a script attached to the Player. Then uncheck is trigger the sphere collider in the enemy. And just leave is trigger the capsule collider to detect raycast.

In this tutorial you have a nice example of this:

https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/s/survival-shooter-tutorial

Comment: Yes, I have what you say. The problem is that I have two colliders with different types and sizes to do two different things (a sphere collider for enable a gameobjects and a capsule collider to do other function) and I need to distinguish them when I enter in the trigger.

Comment: @Angelsm if only the sphere has the trigger, you can use the code I added, you don't need to check if the player triggered the sphere or the capsule. Since there is one single option (the sphere). The you perform your actions

Comment: Sorry, the two colliders have trigger

Comment: @Angelsm I would consider to make is trigger the collider of the Player and remove the is trigger from the sphere. So you will use the "proximity collider" from the script in the player. It will be trigger when the player approaches the obstacle, which I am starting to suspect is an enemy, but you will take actions in the script of the Player. Then you can keep the trigger for the raycast in the obstacle as is trigger, and you will know that the ontriggerenter() in the obstacle script will be triggered when something hit the capsule collider.

Comment: Thank you! I'm trying it. Now, the sphere collider is smaller to enable a canvas gameobjects, gain points, etc, and the capsule collider is bigger to make raycast and touch with the finger in the screen.

Comment: @Angelsm I have edited my answer with an example, with something similar to what you are looking for.

Comment: @Angelsm Ok, if the sphere is smaller than the capsule it is fine, from the script of the player you will be able to distinguish which collider it touched. There you can select if it is the sphere or the capsule

Comment: I just done what you say but, how can I distinguish which collider the player touches? Now the player detects the capsule collider of the obstacle that is bigger.

Comment: @Angelsm I believe you can then apply the same logic you were using in your question. But this time, the two colliders belong to an external object you will need to refer inside onTriggerEnter(). Like other.gameObject.getcomponent... another option is with a counter. If one collider is fully inside the other (Sphere inside capusle), you can keep a counter of colliders entered. And you increase this counter++ in every OnTriggerEnter and you do counter-- in every OnTriggerExit. In case counter == 2, means you entered the sphere. If counter == 1, you are still in the capsule.

Comment: I've added this script to the player but now detects the two colliders. What am I doing wrong?
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
 {
  if (other.gameObject.GetComponent<CheckBoxes>().sCollider) {
   other.GetComponent<CheckBoxes> ().AbrirCamara();
  }
  if (other.gameObject.GetComponent<CheckBoxes>().cCollider) {
   return;
  }
 }

Comment: @Angelsm the problem is you are checking if in the obstacle the collider exists, not which one of the colliders you have entered. The if condition you have just written me will return always true if the collider exists inside the gameobject. Not sure if this will work, but try instead:  if (other.gameObject.GetComponent<CheckBoxes>().sCollider == other)...if (other.gameObject.GetComponent<CheckBoxes>().cCollider == other)

Comment: When you can take a look at this post i just created, please https://stackoverflow.com/q/50580122/6439069

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your game object for **Player** also has attached **collider**

Comment: Yes, player has attached collider. It seems not distinguize the two colliders because it detects the trigger with one collider when I rewrite the code like this: 
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
 {
  if (other.gameObject.tag == "Player") {
    canvasTesoroFoto.SetActive (true);
    canvasTesoroDatos.SetActive (true);
  } 
 }