# Unity - Raycast on child doesn't work

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to enable some gameobjects with a raycast.

I have a principal object which cointains a Child with a collider. This Child contains a text which I want to enable when the Child's collider is hit by the raycast. I've tried with the code bellow but doesn't work. How can I access the child with the raycast?

```
public class SeleccionarTesoro_LIST : MonoBehaviour {
    void Start()
    {
        GameObject[] hitObject = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("TESOROS");
    }

    public void SetHitObjectToActive(GameObject hitObject)
    {
        hitObject.transform.GetChild(0).GetChild(0).gameObject.SetActive (true);
        hitObject.transform.GetChild(0).GetChild(2).gameObject.SetActive (true);
    }

    void Update() {

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)) 
        {
            RaycastHit hit;
            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay (Input.mousePosition);

            if (Physics.Raycast (ray, out hit)) {
                SetHitObjectToActive (hit.collider.gameObject);
            } 
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Let me know if I understood corectly. You have a gameObject with children gameObject. The parent gameObject is disabled, and you want when a raycast hit the children, the parent becames enabled?

Comment: If I am right, a problem may be that if the parent gameobject is not active, you may not be able to detect the child neither.

Comment: @IgnacioAlorre No, I have a parent gameObject with children gameObject. The parent has a sphere collider enabled that I use lo gain points, and the child has a bigger capsule collider enabled to touch it with the finger with raycast to show a text message. The script above is placed in the camera.

Comment: Ok. So what you want is, when the child is touch with the raycast, you want to enable the text message? Or what is the thing you want to enable?

Comment: Yes, when I touch with the raycast I want to enable SetHitObjectToActive

Comment: Does your code get into: SetHitObjectToActive()?

Comment: No, I just updated the script

Comment: Add this inside if (Physics.Raycast (ray, out hit)) { Debug.Log(hit.collider) } And tell us what is the result. Is it always null or doest it change sometimes?

Comment: This text appears in console when I click in the object: InfoObject (UnityEngine.CapsuleCollider)
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
SeleccionarTesoro_LIST:Update() (at Assets/_TES/Scripts/SeleccionarTesoro_LIST.cs:43)

Comment: That is good, it is detecting the capsule collider properly. Not do the same here: 
public void SetHitObjectToActive(GameObject hitObject){Debug.Log(hitObject)}

Comment: It appears this error:
UnityException: Transform child out of bounds
SeleccionarTesoro_LIST.SetHitObjectToActive (UnityEngine.GameObject hitObject) (at Assets/_TES/Scripts/SeleccionarTesoro_LIST.cs:26)
SeleccionarTesoro_LIST.Update () (at Assets/_TES/Scripts/SeleccionarTesoro_LIST.cs:45)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments, I thing you are trying to reach the child in a wrong way.

Start by calling each gameObject with a name. For example:

- MainGameObject
- ChildCapsule
- ChildText

Now, to access the child do like this:

```
public void SetHitObjectToActive(GameObject hitObject)
{
     hitObject.transform.Find("ChildCapsule").gameObject.transform.Find("ChildText").gameObject.SetActive (true);
}
```

Comment: It's true. I was reaching the text messages in the parent gameobject, not in the child. I've placed them in the right order and now It works fine. Thank you Ignacio!!!!

Comment: Hi Ignacio! I've posted a new question. This is the link in case you can help me: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50831424/6439069. Thanks in advantage!!

Comment: @Angelsm I will check it later

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to get the child of `hitObject` like this `hitObject.transform.GetChild(0)`, but what if the `hitObject` doesnt have a child, then your program will throw a `null exception`, so first you have to check if what you want to access exist and then access it.
for example:

```
public void SetHitObjectToActive(GameObject hitObject)
{
     if(hitObject.transform.childCount>0){
           GameObjectchild = child hitObject.transform.GetChild(0);
           if(GameObjectchild.childCount>0 ){
             GameObjectchild.GetChild(0).gameObject.SetActive (true);} 
     }
}
```

but overall I think it is better if you first check to see if the object that you have collided with is the right object and after that made sure do what you want

for that, you can use `tags` or `names` or `layers`,
first, if you want to use tags then assign a tag to the object you want to    specify for example enemy

```
 if (Physics.Raycast (ray, out hit)) {
    if( hit.collider.gameObject.tag  == "enemy" )
         {
            SetHitObjectToActive (hit.collider.gameObject);
        } 
 }
```