# Make a list of achievements in a scroll view

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to make a list of all the achievements the player can earn in my game. With the code bellow I retrieve the achievements from the server and I've made a scroll list in Unity to show them but only the first row appears. I'd like to show the name, description and currency of all of them. I'd also like to change the color of the achievements the player has earned if bool earned variable is true.

I've attached below an image of the list I'd like to appear and a screenshot of the scrollview I have in the hierarchy.

```
new GameSparks.Api.Requests.LogEventRequest ()
        .SetEventKey ("LISTACHIEVEMENTS")
        .Send ((response) => {

            if(!response.HasErrors)
            {
                Debug.Log("List Achivements Loaded Sucessfully...");
                GSData scriptData = response.ScriptData;
                List<GSData> achievements = scriptData.GetGSDataList("achievements"); //retrieve the array of objects
                for (int i = 0; i < achievements.Count; i++)
                {
                    string name = achievements[i].GetString("name");
                    string description = achievements[i].GetString("description");
                    int? currency1Award = achievements[i].GetInt("currency1Award");
                    bool? earned = achievements[i].GetBoolean("earned");

                    Debug.Log(name);
                    Debug.Log(description);
                    Debug.Log(currency1Award);
                    Debug.Log(earned);

                    GameObject tempFile = Instantiate (filePrefab, contentRef.transform);
                    Text tempName = tempFile.transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<Text>();
                    Text tempDescription = tempFile.transform.GetChild(1).GetComponent<Text>();
                    Text tempCurrency1Award = tempFile.transform.GetChild(2).GetComponent<Text>();

                    tempName.text = name;
                    tempDescription.text = description;
                    tempCurrency1Award.text = currency1Award.ToString();
                }

            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log("Error Loading Achivements...");
            }
        });
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you looked at any of the tutorials for Unity? After a quick Google, [I found this](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/projects/roll-ball-tutorial/displaying-score-and-text).

Comment: I just updated my question. I've got to appears only one row in the scroll list. What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You assign the elements (name, description, currency) to the same UITexts.
It is like you try to store 20 numbers (0,1,2...19), but you only have one variable (int) to store them.

Try to create the texts in the for loop as much as you need.
Here is an example:

```
public GameObject filePrefab; // to be able to instantiate new "files"

...

for (...)
{
    // Create the file and assign the valuse
    GameObject tempFile = Instantiate( filePrefab);
    Text tempName = tempFile.GetChild(0).GetComponenet<Text>();
    Text tempDescription = tempFile.GetChild(1).GetComponenet<Text>();
    Text tempCurrency1Award = tempFile.GetChild(2).GetComponenet<Text>();

    // Here you can set there position, etc.
    ...

    // Assign the values
    tempName.text = name;
    tempDescription.text = description;
    tempCurrency1Award.text = currency1Award.ToString();  
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much. I just updated my script adding the bool "earned" variable and I'd also like to change the color of the achievements the player has earned if this variable retrieve "true" value (like the screenshot). How can I do it?

Comment: @Angelsm `if(earned) { messWithColors(); }`

Comment: @Dániel Kőcs How can I change the color of the achievements the player has earned if this variable retrieve "true" value (like the screenshot)?

Comment: @Draco18s How can I make darker all the row?

Comment: Alter the `Image` component's `color` property.

Comment: @Draco18s I've tried with the code  bellow but doesn't work fine. There are 2 achievements earned but only one changes the color.  if((bool)earned) 
      { 
       filePrefab.GetComponent<Image>().color = new Color32(255,255,225,100);
      }

Comment: If you like to make changes on the objects store them in a list. Like you create a List<GameObjects> listOfAchievments; (or similar) and in the for loop, when you instantiate a tempfile, add it to the list.
Once you need to change one of them just iterate through the list (foreach or for loop) and change the one(s) that is needed

Comment: @Angelsm The color is a *multiplier.* You told it to multiply with white, which does nothing.

Comment: @Draco18s I've changed the color to (85,10,100,100) but only affects to the first element of the list again

Comment: You need to apply the color to the instantiated copy, not the prefab.

Comment: Hi DánielKőcs and  @Draco18s I have a new post relative this question. If you could help me I thank you. This is the link: https://stackoverflow.com/q/51113183/6439069